# subclassing specialized generic class in swift

Tags: swift, generics, overriding

I have a generic class DataSource over AnyObject.
with a subscript function to pull some items from the cache.

When I subclass of DataSource for example the subscript function stops getting considered an override and subsequently invoking it on an object of type SpecialDataSource will call the super class version.

```
class DataSource<T: AnyObject>: NSObject {
    var cache: [T]?

    subscript(idx: Int) -> T? {
        if let hasStash = cache {
            if idx < hasStash.count{
                return hasStash[idx]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


class SpecialDataSource<T> : DataSource<NSNumber> {
//The following declaration will generate:
//subscript does not override any subscript from its superclass

    override subscript(idx: Int) -> T? {
        if let hasStash = cache {
            if idx < hasStash.count{
                return hasStash[idx] as? T
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

after experimenting with this in Playground i found that this would not have happened if the SpecialDataSource declaration was:

```
class SpecialDataSource<T> : DataSource<T>
```

I need the subclass to be based of a common object so i can stuff a few of them in a homogenous array.

so this declaration doesn't provide that option.

When i got this error it sounded like `DataSource<NSNumber>` is complete different superclass.

Any Idea whats going wrong here? Im trying to understand why my SpecialDataSource can't seem to override this function.

=============== Current Solution ===========

The only way i was able to work around this problem is by specializing the return type of the subscript to NSNumber, with that in place the override did actually do the job.

Not sure if there is a better solution. Please let me know. I will be happy to try it out.

```
class SpecialDataSource2<T: NSNumber> : DataSource2<NSNumber> {
    override subscript(idx: Int) -> NSNumber? {
        if let hasStash = cache {
            if idx < hasStash.count{
                return hasStash[idx] as? T
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataSource<NSNumber>` is indeed a different superclass. Different code gets generated!

It's not really making sense that you're specializing the parent class to use NSNumber. What's the deeper intent / goal? What goes wrong if you follow the `T` pattern in both child and parent?

Suppose the parent class had another method `xyz` that used `T`. Well now that's been bound to `NSNumber`, so `xyz` expects an `NSNumber`. And any child class of course inherits the `xyz` method. But now suppose your child class is instantiated with `NSString` for T. What is the compiler supposed to do with method `xyz` for an instance of `SpecialDataSource`? Do you see the inherent conflict?

As "magically flexible" generics are, they actually come with quite a few very specific rules.

Comment: The idea of specializing the generic over NSNumber for example is just to be able to derive two different subclasses that can have the same base class so i can stuff them in a homogenous array

Comment: I agree with your example of xyz method, that makes sense to me too. I'm gonna try to consider different approach, not sure what yet

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to define the subclass like this:

```
class SpecialDataSource<T, U> : DataSource<T> { ... }
```

That adds some complexity - `SpecialDataSource` now requires two generic types.

But it also adds flexibility. You could have superclasses of `DataSource<NSNumber>` or `DataSource<NSWhateverYouWant>`.

Also, I believe your subclass's subscript function would look something like this:

```
subscript(idx: Int) -> U? {
    if let hasStash = cache {
        if idx < hasStash.count{
            return hasStash[idx] as? U
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

...and the override would not be necessary (I'm not in a spot where I could test this.)

Comment: I don't have a need second generic type for this class in this case :/